# counter metrics representation in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I want to know the number of requests in a given time.
I'm using Grafana to show data and now I have this simple table
[image]

for example, this table represents the number of requests to a specific API. but it is an ascending table and I can't compare the number of requests in 8 and 10 because
 `the number of requests in 10 = number of requests in 8 + number of requests between 8 and 10`

 and I only want the number of requests between 8 and 10

Comment: You have a rather strange graph there. What is your metric and what type is it? It looks a bit like counter, but decreases at moments, and that shouldn't happen to counters. What is you query?

Comment: because my server restarted so the counter set to 0